# Is Ubuntu Touch created in C++?

Tags: application-development

The reason I ask is because C++ is more efficient. Since  Ubuntu SDK provides python for quicker programing but will it be more efficient than C++ and does Ubuntu provide a virtual machine for Ubuntu phone or will it be direct to machine code as C++ because it would be more efficient and especially easier integration with regular Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It's written in C++ and QML, you can get the source code yourself here: http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unitynext/

You can run the phone and tablet shell on your desktop, no need for a virtual machine.